# Angular2 how to pass application config from MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, app-config, angular2-services

Trying to upgrade from RC4 => Angular 2.1.0

```
 var native = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
 var myattr = native.getAttribute("applicationConfig");
```

I am getting:

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: native.getAttribute is not a function

My objective is to ass applicationConfig from MVC side to angular.
It used to work that we would set a global object and access it through window['objName'] on the angular side. How do I pass my config to angular now? I have tried elementRef trick but it seems like it's not working at all in 2.1.0

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/boot-server"
         asp-prerender-webpack-config="webpack.config.js"
         applicationConfig="@ViewBag.appConfig">Loading...</app>
```

I am using the element ref in my bootstrapped component - AppComponent

Answer (score 0):

When my ng2 app starts, I need to pass a few server-side variables to the app.  Here is what my razor view looks like:

```html
@ModelType MyProject.Models.MasterViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <base href="/">
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/inline.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <app>Loading...</app>
  <script>
    var APP_SETTINGS = {
      apiUrl: "@Model.ApiUrl",
      ipAddress: "@Model.IpAddress",
      referredFrom: "@Model.ReferredFrom",
      browser: "@Model.Browser"
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/main.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then when I want to reference APP_SETTINGS, I do something like the following (within the context of my ng2 app):

```js
export interface IAppSettings {
    apiUrl: string;
    ipAddress: string;
    referredFrom: string;
    browser: string;
}
declare const APP_SETTINGS: IAppSettings;
```